# Kendo Grid DateColumn show NaN/NaN/NaN

Tags: angularjs, datetime, kendo-grid

In every grid (Kendo for AngujarJs) on my project that contains a DateTime value I'm getting this `NaN/NaN/NaN`

Here is my schema:

```
schema: {
            model: {
                id: 'RequestId',
                fields: {
                    RequestId: { type: 'number' },
                    RequestNumber: {  type: 'number'},
                    FileNumber: { type: 'string' },
                    RegistrationDate: { type: 'datetime' },
                    RequestStatus: { type: 'string' },
                    UnitName: { type: 'string' }
                }
            }
        }
```

I've tried with `RegistrationDate: { type: 'string' },` or `RegistrationDate: { type: 'date' },` but nothing change, also I tried this on my `columns`:

```
{
    field: 'RegistrationDate',
    title: 'Fecha de Registro',
    type: 'date'
},
```

Or `type: 'datetime'` and nothing.

Here is what I get from the server:

[image]

Any idea on how to make it work? Its pretty basic to show a Date in a grid, I know, in other projects I have no problem, but as you can see, I tried all I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    field: 'RegistrationDate',
    title: 'Fecha de Registro',
    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"
}
```